# Is magnetic susceptibility infinite at Curie temperature for a ferromagnetic material?

Tags: ferromagnetism

By **Curie-Weiss law** , $$\chi_m = \frac{C}{T-T_c}$$ Where, C is Curie constant and $T_c$ is Curie temperature. If T = $T_c$ would then $\chi_m$ be $\infty$ ? But by theory , at Curie temperature the ferromagnetic material becomes paramagnetic. But , for a paramagnetic material, $$\chi_m\gt1$$ How is this possible?

---

Please point out and explain where am I going wrong.

Comment: It is true that the susceptibility diverges at the critical temperature. I am unsure where you got that $\chi_{m}<1$ for a paramagnet?

Comment: Oops! You are right. For paramagnetic materials magnetic susceptibility is not less than unity but its greater than unity. However in many of the textbooks its specified that $\chi_m$ is very small. For example water has susceptibility in the order of $10^{-7}$.

Comment: I am not aware of this either, as far as I know the definition of a paramagnet is that the susceptibility is $\chi_{m}>0$.